# Disable double click on jQuery AJAX event

Tags: jquery, ajax, double-click

I have a pagination button that runs an Ajax function to pull new results on the page. Everything is working fine, the only thing is that if I double click the button, I get the results doubled, because it is making 2 identical calls.

I know there are many workaround for this thing, but nothing seems to work completely.

Now I'm using a var as a flag...

```
var isPaging = 0;
$('.container').on('click', '.bh-pagination-button', function(){

    if (!isPaging) {

        isPaging = 1;

        callBehanceProjectsList();

        isPaging = 0;
    }
});
```

It seems working if I'm kind of slow, but if I'm very quick in clicking twice or three times, it makes nth calls, all of them identical.

Then I saw there are other solutions out there:

```
one();
unbind();
die();

etc...
```

Those ones actually could work, the problem is that once I disable the click event, I can not reenable it, and I need to click many times after the pagination ends.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
$('.container').on('click', '.bh-pagination-button', function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  callBehanceProjectsList();
  $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

This way, the button will be disabled just before the pagination starts, and will automatically enable after the pagination ends. This will prevent multiple clicks on the button, hence the need for a specific variable will also be eliminated.

Comment: it seems a cool solution, but it is not working. I even tried leaving only the "prop disable" without reenabling it at the end, but it keeps working normally.

Comment: @rolfo85 - Can you show your HTML? Update the question with it.

Comment: It's a plugin and all HTML is dynamically generated. Including the button I'm clicking.

Comment: tryiing to achieve the same thing, why not try updating the css property with pointer events none?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced a similar problem. My solution is _

```
   $('#acceptButton').attr("disabled", true);
```

Here `acceptButton` is button id.

Comment: Depending on your version of jQuery you might wanna use `prop()` over `attr()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use Jquery.BlockUI.Js.

Here is the sample code for that,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Button3").click(function() {
    console.log('d');
        $.blockUI();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.unblockUI({
                onUnblock: function() {
                //Write your unblock logic
                    alert('onUnblock');
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

You can even unblock it after getting response from the ajax call, this seems to be a better solution for your situation.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwjsgxrp/

Comment: Thanks but I can't use an external resource. I'm building a plugin so I'd rather use jquery only